# how to set the cursor: hand for jquery data table

Tags: javascript, css, html, datatables

I need to set the cursor: hand for particular jquery data table row selection .I try this code but not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#table tr").css('cursor', 'hand');
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the answer , simple :

```
<table class="display" id="table" style="cursor:pointer" width="100%"> </table>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table tr").css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

Comment: it gives hand symbol try it

Comment: i was added fiddle for you. check:                                       http://jsfiddle.net/yCz4k/

Comment: this doesn't work for jquery datatables.  I voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

HTML

```
<div class="teaser">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-189-137-4.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.teaser {
   border-radius: 100%;
overflow: auto;
display: table-caption;
}
.js
{
   cursor: -webkit-grab;
   cursor: -Moz-grab;

}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".teaser").addClass("js")
    });
```